# Is there an adapter to convert my USB internet dongle to Ethernet RJ45 male

Tags: usb, networking, ethernet, network-adapter

I have a USB dongle for the internet. I want to use the internet in LAN RJ45 mode for my application.

Instead of buying a costly router (~1500 Rs) for the conversion, can I buy a converter or any technique for the same?

Comment: What is the USB dongle you have? Would [something like this](https://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/usb-network-adapters/USB-3-to-Gigabit-Ethernet-NIC-Network-Adapter~USB31000S) be what you need? It would *replace* whatever dongle you're using.

Comment: Although you didn't describe the dongle, it sounds like maybe you're using a USB Wi-Fi adapter? The dongle linked by @Romen would allow you to connect to the same router that is currently providing the wireless internet to your existing dongle, but via a wired ethernet (RJ45) connection.